# Form input array $_GET comma separated in URL

Tags: php, arrays, forms, get

I have a form:

```
<form action="results.php" method="get">
<select name="genres[]">
<option value="jazz"></option>
<option value="blues"></option>
<option value="rock"></option>
</select>
</form>
```

After submitting the form, in the URL the input becomes `example.com/?genres%5B%5D=jazz&genres%5B%5D=blues&genres%5B%5D=rock`

Next to that it doesn't look very nice, I have multiple inputs in my form (and around 18 genres) so if a user selects a lot, the URL becomes very long. I'd like it to become `/?genres=jazz,blues,rock`

Now I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909138/a-get-input-parameter-that-is-an-array), but it doesn't state how to make the cleaner URL. Next to that, I have to use the input as an array, eg `$genres = $_GET['genres']` to use in another function.

Comment: Assuming you are using apache, you should be able to achieve this using .htaccess rewrite rules. See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: You could use POST instead?

Comment: I can use POST but if people share the URL others wouldn't see the same results, that's why I'm using GET.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#go").click(function(){
               var g = $("#genres").val();
               var href = 'results.php?genres=';
               if(g != null) {
                   href += g;
               }
               document.location.href=href;
           });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
<select id="genres" size="3" multiple>
<option value="jazz">jazz</option>
<option value="blues">blues</option>
<option value="rock">rock</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="go" name="submit" id="go">
</body>
</html>
```

in results.php you should:

```
$g = isset($_GET['genres'])?$_GET['genres']:"";
$genres = explode(",",$g);
```

i have removed the form completely because the genres are now sent by `document.location.href`. The `.val()` function of jquery returns the selected values like expected (imploded by `,`)

Comment: Looks like a nice solution, but the URL still returns like I've described in my question. Also it's a bit more complex (I just realized) because I have multiple pages with the same form so the return URL in the javascript depends on which page the user is. Thanks anyway, upvote.