# PHP Array in URL nicer

Tags: php, arrays, url

I'm currently thinking about following problem.

On one page I pass `GET` data through form. 
URL after that looks like this:

> example.com/data/**array[]=1&array[]=2&array[]=3**

And I would like to make it look like this:

> example.com/data/**array[]=1,2,3**

It's a search filter page, that's why I don't use `POST`, so eg. a user can send URL to friend.

I use Codeigniter framework. Any ideas guys?

Comment: If it's a form, you should be passing your data using POST. Store it in the session if you need to persist data across pages

Comment: You can't really do that using default url parsing, you'll need to create a parser of your own. But don't you think that would be a little too much work for something like that

Comment: You could just have `array` be a single parameter that holds `1,2,3` and explode on `,`. That would give you an array

Comment: You can alter the form before submission so it would send only one value, e.g. `.../?some-value=1,2,3`. You can then process the value in PHP and treat it as an array, e.g. `explode(',',$_GET['some-value'])`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens if you have a HTML form where multiple items have the same NAME attribute. You can name the form elements differently, for example option1, option2, option3 and check for `$_GET["option$i"]` where $i = 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple items. But your solution doesn't make url shorter or nicer. Any idea how to change Form before sending without JS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019491/form-input-array-get-comma-separated-in-url I have same problem than this guy. Do you have any idea how to do that without JAVASCRIPT? Eg. with htaccess

Comment: I'm not aware of any possibility to do this without some scripting. With JS, you can encode the options any way you want, but without it, no idea, sorry. Apache URL rewriting might be able to do it but then you are making your site dependent of server type and configuration.

Comment: Or maybe change the form to POST and from there redirect to a page with the encoded search params... But not sure how you could fill up the form when coming in through the encoded URL... again, JS is needed.