# Special characters and array in URL

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, url, get

I have page listing with schools, and search filter with CHECKBOX INPUTS.

For example one criteria is school's city. So when you submit the filter form URL looks like this:
**

> www.schools.com/schools/**?city%5B%5D=1&city%5B%5D=2&city%5B%5D=3&city%5B%5D=4**

And I would like to make it look like this.

> www.schools.com/schools/****?city[]=1,2,3,4**

So basicly I need solution for two problems:

1. How to pass multiple variables with same name via array with nice url?
2. How to keep special characters (like "[", "]") in the URL?

I use **Codeigniter** framework.
Thank you guys.

// Edit For **Anonymous**
I would like to make this simple form:

```
  <form action="" method="get">
  <input name="kraj[]" type="checkbox" value="1">     
  <input name="kraj[]" type="checkbox" value="2">
  <input type="submit" value="send">
  </form>
```

When user checks both inputs, send data to url like that:
**example.com/?kraj[]=1,2** 

not like this: **example.com/?kraj[]=1&kraj[]=2**
I know how to handle it after getting it in required format but I don't know how to send it like that.

Comment: Special characters *are not valid* in URLs. That's why they were encoded for you in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the URL look better by using `-` to separate the values since that special character does not get changed.  This works perfectly for me and should keep the check-boxes checked using the `$_GET` method in addition to some JavaScript:

```
<?php
$city_array = explode('-',$_GET['city']);
?>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if (isset($_GET['city']) && in_array('1', $city_array)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" <?php if (isset($_GET['city']) && in_array('2', $city_array)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" <?php if (isset($_GET['city']) && in_array('3', $city_array)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>/>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" <?php if (isset($_GET['city']) && in_array('4', $city_array)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>/>
<form method='GET' action='' id='form'>
<input name='city' type='hidden' value='' id='hidden'/>
</form>
<input type='submit' onclick='checkboxarray()'/>
<script>
function checkboxarray() {
var checked = [];
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; i++) {
var checkbox = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i];
if (checkbox.checked) {
checked.push(checkbox.value);
}
}
var checked = checked.toString().replace(/,/g,'-');
document.getElementById('hidden').value = checked;
document.getElementById('form').submit();
}
</script>
```

For example, the new URL may be: `www.schools.com/schools/?city=1-4`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand how to explode but I don't know how to set it before submiting form with checkboxes. Automatically, it submits it like I've written.

Comment: Basicaly form looks like this. `<label class="checkbox">
  <input name="kraj[]" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if (isset($kraj) and in_array(1, $kraj)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
  Bratislavský
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
  <input name="kraj[]" type="checkbox" value="2" <?php if (isset($kraj) and in_array(2, $kraj)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>>
   Trnavský
</label>`

Comment: Currently it's same problem that this guy was solving. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019491/form-input-array-get-comma-separated-in-url But I would like to see non-javascript solution.

Comment: Would you be against using JavaScript to check if it is checked then submitting the form?

Comment: My answer has been updated to fit what I believe you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you for answer but it's still not exact what I need. Check this search filter: http://digitalne-fotoaparaty.heureka.sk/ When you check more checkboxes URL looks like this: http://digitalne-fotoaparaty.heureka.sk/f:p:653,654,655/ (values separated by coma)

Comment: It should not be separating them by commas unless you changed the symbol that it puts between the JavaScript values.

Comment: Yes, I understand I posted you this website because it's how I would like to make mine working. I'll edit my first problem and describe what I want more detailed. But again thank you for your reply.

Comment: Oh if you want `,` instead of `-`, that is easy.  However, one warning (this is the reason I didn't use a comma in the first place) `,` will be changed to an ugly character like spaces are.  Would you like me to update my answer to the ugly comma or keep it at the nice `-`?

Comment: No, no you propably don't understand what I would like to do. Please check my first question post, I've edited it.

Comment: You want the url like this: `example.com/?kraj[]=1,2` and mine is like this: `example.com/?city=1,2`.  Is the problem the word city or not having the `[]`?

Comment: No.. The problem with your solution is that old GET variables are still in url so it looks like this: example.com/?city[]=1&city[]=2&city[]=1,2

Comment: Oh the reason for that is because you are adding the inputs in a separate form.  Leave those inputs out of a form.  Therefore, they will mess up the link.  The form that I have in the question is the only one you will need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! The only problem for me is, that it doesn't work properly without Javascript. I know there's way to do it without Javascript because the website that I sent you has Non-js solution.

Comment: There would not be a way to use `[]` though.  Therefore, `example.com/?kraj[]=1,2` would always result in special characters.

Comment: I was thinking about .htaccess solution but I think it's too complicated. // I don't need to have there "[]" strictly. The problem is that I can't find any Non-js solution. Basically, I need to edit GET variable before submiting or somehow.

Comment: Finally, I solved it with simple PHP redirect. Thank you very much for your time spent on helping me.